# Calculating dissipation of a CCR powered via a full bridge rectifier

Tags: constant-current, rms, full-bridge

I'm putting together a string of UV/purple LEDs for photoetching purposes.

The idea is the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuR1WW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 80 LEDs are in series, and have a typical Vf=3,5 V. Since the maximum Vak across the CCR is 45 V, I'm also adding a resistor (ideally 1,45 KOhm, I will check later an appropriate standard value), just in case the supply voltage reaches the full 253 V.

This is the CCR I'm using: [NSI45020AT1G](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NSI45020A-D.PDF)

This is the application note I'm following: [AND8433/D](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8433-D.PDF)

Now to my problem: I wanted to check how much power the CCR should dissipate and I tried to follow the application note.

Quoting page 3:

> Thermal Analysis of Design Example 1
>   (120 VAC, 38 LEDs)
>   The power dissipation of the CCR for Figure 3 is determined by:
>
> (Vak rms) x (IREG*Duty Cycle )
>
> Vak rms = Vbridge rms - LED string VFrms
>
> (120 Vbr rms-(38 x 3.3 V LED x 0.707 ) x (30 mA x 50%)
>
> = 31 V rms x 15 mA = 465 mW

I'm confused by the calculation for Vak rms, in particular by the 0,707 factor. And wh

This is how I would have calculated the Vakrms:

$$Vbridge =Vpk*sin(2\pi f t)$$

where Vpk is 350 V for a 230*1,1 V supply, f=50 Hz.

Most of the current flows when

Vbridge > 1,8 V [the CCR overhead] + 80*(3,5 V) + R1*20 mA

So,

$$\left |\sin (314  t)\right | > \frac{1,8 V + 80\, (3,5 V) + R1\; 20 mA}{Vpk}$$

I plug the whole thing in Wolfram|Alpha and find that the on time is 6 ms.

6 ms * 50 Hz = 0,3

So the duty rate is more or less 30%.

Vak rms = (Vbridgerms - 80*Vf -R1*20 mA)*0,3

and Vbridgerms is 230 V (or 250 V at most)

Am I doing something wrong here? And what the idea behind the calculation on the paper is? In particular, what is the 0,707 ($ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} $ ?) factor for?

Thanks

Comment: Vak is the voltage across the CCR which is sinusoidal so the 0.707 factor is to convert it to RMS so it can be used to calculate power.

Comment: I thought that the conversion factor is sqrt(2) for sine signals? Or the fact it is rectified changes something?

Comment: the 0.707 factor is 1/sqrt(2) to go from Vp to VRMS

Comment: And just for a reminder you probably know this already but the voltage out of the bridge rectifier is gonna be 700V peak because when you rectify the ac to pulsing DC the Vpp AC turnes in to the Vp DC

Comment: Oh, right, the equation is the other way round so I have to divide and 1/sqrt(2) is sqrt(2)/2. Well that was easier than I expected...
As for the Vpp, I actually had never thought of this. It is because the rectified wave is actually alternating between +320V, neutral and neutral, -320V, right? But I guess this does not changes my calculations since the voltage across the rails is still 320 V through the whole cycle.

Comment: This comment is for the next time that you ask a question.  Please PLEASE fully expand your acronyms. Standard is to Capitalize the first letter of each word in the phrase the first time you need to use the phrase. You can use the acronym freely thereafter.